# Не могу получить название коммитов и и количество изменений/добавлений в нем

Tags: python, django, github, github-api

Всем привет! Я делаю програму чтобы получать инфу с гита о своих коммитах, но не могу получить само имя коммита и количество изменений/добавлений в нём, помогите пожалуйста!
вот код:

```
@csrf_protect
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def get_all_commits_in_GIT(request, author):
if request.method == "GET":
    g = Github()
    repo = g.get_repo(author + '/api')
    data = {}
    for commit in repo.get_commits():
        data[commit.sha] = {
            "url_for_commit": 'https://github.com/{0}/api/commit/{1}'.format(author, commit.sha),
            "author": author,
            "date": str(commit.last_modified),
            "name_commit": ???,
            "changes": ???,
            "added": ???
        }

    return Response({"data": data, "status": ')'})
```